# Netlogo: How to set the id of a turtle to the value of a patch

Tags: netlogo

This is my code where I suppose it has to be written, but I don't know how to get rid of the "You can't use ID in a patch context, because ID is turtle-only" error. Blancas are White pieces on a board, negras are black pieces on a board.

```
to actualizarTablero
  ask patches with [any? blancas-on patch pxcor pycor] [
    set id value
    let id-local id
    set plabel value 
    ]
    ask patches with [any? negras-on patch pxcor pycor] [
    set value id
    let id-local id
    set plabel value
  ]
    ask patches with [not any? negras-on patch pxcor pycor and not any? blancas-on patch pxcor pycor] [
    set value 0
    set plabel value
  ]

end
```

Comment: What's suppose to happen? The issue is that your patches is using ID which is a turtle member rather than a patch member.

Comment: please show us the `patches-own` and `turtles-own` statements

Comment: It would also help to have more helpful names for the variables and even in-line comments as to what the code is doing and why.  Names like "value" are not very helpful to reviewers.  By the way, for blancas you are setting id to value, but in negras you are doing the opposite -- setting value to id.  I think you could also just use "ask patches " to set the value of all patches to zero at the start of actualizarTablero and skip the more complex "ask-patches with" logic at the end.  The other two checks would then over-write the zeros where relevant.

Comment: Hi Pablo, and welcome to StackOverflow! We'll need more details about what you're trying to do in order to be able to help, but there is already one thing I can say: unless you're doing something very unusual, you probably don't need an id at all. NetLogo works best when you deal with agents and agentsets directly. Using id (or `who` numbers) usually just gets in the way and makes everything a bit more awkward then it needs to be.